# Word which encompasses both "logs" and "notes"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm building a software component which will allow users to view both automatically-generated log entries and human-created notes in the same list. Both are time-stamped and will be displayed in the same list in chronological order.

I'm hoping to find a word or short phrase which will describe both of these things. I'm currently using "message", but that doesn't sit well with me; it implies a more active form of communication. I considered "records" and "entries", but they both feel overly generic.

I would like to be able to say something along the lines of

> This is the _____ component. It combines the data in the notes and log components.

Comment: @V0ight I'm not very happy with "records". The reason for this is more due to the specific terminology of technology; record is the word used in programming for "a piece of data stored in a database". To me, a "records" component sounds nearly as generic as a "data" component.

Comment: how about *archive*, as in a *collection of records*: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/archive............ used in your sentence, *the archival component*

Comment: Dis you consider *history*?

Comment: @alwayslearning "history" is not bad. What would you call a single element of the history?

Comment: @V0ight to me "archive" has a strong connotation that the list is static: no new records will ever be added.

Comment: I am afraid the best I can think of for *a single element of the history* is *record*. I know you don't like it, though!

Comment: @alwayslearning I might be able to stomach "record" as long as the component is not just named "records" or "record list". I suppose "activity" might also work in place of "history".

Comment: Sure, yes! *Activity* should work in place of *history*. Funnily enough, I did consider *activity* earlier but dismissed it as unsatisfactory. Wait, *journal* may work a bit better!

Comment: idk how you got from logs/notes to activity, but ok, whatever works haha

Comment: I'll plump for @V0ight's suggestion. *Archive* might feel static, because on the web *being archived* can mean something like inactivating. However, most *archives* grow continuously, as any archivist with a space crunch can attest. Alternatively, depending on how you will present the information, perhaps something like *timeline*?

Comment: Personally, I would consider the human-created notes, since they're time-stamped and recorded just as the machine-generated logs are, to be a subset of "log".  They are just logging a different kind of event.

Comment: Log Notes is what I would say.

Comment: You're asking for a generic term to describe pieces of text which are already described in very generic terms ("log" and "note"), but "record" and "entry" are "overly generic"? Might as well make up a word, your requirements are impossibly narrow.

Comment: What @MontyHarder said. A program can log information, and so can a human. In your case, both are logging information to the same file. It is a log file.

Comment: @MontyHarder you are conceptually correct. It's hard to imagine a more confusing way to name it though. "The log component contains the notes component and the log component."

Answer (score 13):

You may consider *[journal](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/j/journal.htm)*:

> A journal is a location of stored activities or events occurring on a
>   computer or network.

Comment: As a term of art in the IT field, "journal" has a very specific meaning.  Journaling systems are able to use a journal to track individual changes to the system state, and can replay all or part(s) of the journal to reproduce those changes after restoring the overall system state from a backup (or if the journal is designed to allow it, back out selected changes).
Classic use case is to find the transaction that blew up a DB and replay everything right up to the previous transaction.

If the log can't do these things, it's not a "journal".

Comment: The hyperlink provided in the answer has 2 definitions; the first is what I used and the second is about the Journaling File System.

Comment: The use of journal in this sense predates computing. Before there were journaling file systems, journals were used in accounting to keep detailed records of all transactions, with the express purpose of being able to use them to reproduce work, back out changes, and so forth.

Comment: @alwayslearning The prevalence of journaling filesystems, databases, etc. has rendered any historical meaning of "journal" in IT obsolete.  No one would use the term if it's solely to provide human-readable descriptions and lacks the ability to replay and/or back out transactions.

Comment: @MontyHarder Livejournal disagrees.

Comment: @MontyHarder Actually, journaling as an IT term is far more likely to be associated with file systems than databases. DBAs and database documentation are much more likely to call them transaction logs rather than journals. Same principle, different term. Frankly it's probably a good thing, as file system performance is relevant to database performance tuning, and it would be pretty confusing to talk about the impact of journaling on journaling.

Comment: Also, any assumption that an IT-specific technical term has rendered a common English word obsolete is pretty silly. Most computer users are NOT IT professionals.

Comment: @MontyHarder Surely you must have heard of systemd, now the de facto standard for system startup and maintenance in most every linux distribution. Systemd logs everything to its _journal_, and you use `journalctl` to read it. It is used just like the old syslog component - that is, a plain old system log. If you think IT people will get confused, they have much bigger problems right now.

Comment: @pipe I have heard of it, but have done my best not to be involved with it, as it is inherently far more complex than SysV style init scripts, which are so simple that a fifth-grader,  after a few minutes' instruction, ought to be able to understand the sequence in which they're executed.  (system: not so much.)
 I shouldn't be surprised that they'd overloaded "journal" in the process.

Comment: @barbecue The people interested in reading log files generated by computer programs tend to be IT professionals or perhaps hobbyists who largely share the vocabulary. The common computer user just wants the thing to work.

Comment: @MontyHarder The people interested in reading logs are people whose job it is to read those logs, regardless of whether they are IT professionals or hobbyists. Anyone who's ever used a financial package,  business management system or CRM system knows what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 7):

A log entry would be an event. But this is not a term that can be used for notes very well. However perhaps the nicely ambiguous term [annotation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/annotation) can serve?

> A note by way of explanation or comment added to a text or diagram:
> *marginal annotations*

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/annotation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annotation

Comment: This is also probably the most scientific/technical friendly word, besides possibly journaling (which is used by HFS+ file systems on Macs)

Comment: The [verb form works](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337200/word-which-encompasses-both-logs-and-notes/337282#337282) as part of a phrase, but ambiguously standing alone, the noun form does not encompass the log aspect. "marginal annotations" is also ambiguous. Are they in the margin, of little worth, or perhaps both?

Answer (score 7):

***History***

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/history

During our last project "history" is what we named a similar collection of chronological system generated logs and user generated comments.

We referred to the individual instances as a "history item" or "history record"

Comment: Depending on what the log and note entries record, you could be even more specific, e.g. "Transaction History" or "User History".

Answer (score 3):

[**Diary**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diary) (TFD):

> - A daily record of events or measurable phenomena, usually kept to track patterns over time: kept a diary of blood sugar levels.
> - A book or computer file used for keeping such a record.

The term has been used to record "sessions" in softwares like Matlab ([write to a diary file](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-a-diary-file.html)) or Octave ([Help to Log, Save and Edit](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~hanson/Octave/OctaveLogSave.html)).

Comment: I strongly associate the word "diary" with belonging to a specific person.

Comment: @Will Kunkel I am afraid computers or systems will be considered as "persons" soon

Answer (score 3):

In the context of Information Technology, specifically the nomenclature we use for our Salesforce Database, we use the term **Documentation**

> The usually printed instructions, comments, and information for using a particular piece or system of computer software or hardware
>
> Source: [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/documentation)

We use "documentation" as a catch-all term for the automated logs generated by the various moving parts of the system as well as the manual system changes and notes added by our administrators. When we need to refer to a single part of the documentation, we call it an **entry**.

Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: As an IT person, I would say logs are not "documentation", which consists of relatively static material prepared to explain how the system (should) work[s].  Logs, in contrast, are records of events that reflect how the system responded to various stimuli.  Confusingly, one may use "document" as a noun to refer to a change order/log, or a verb to refer to the production thereof.  Such documents may become incorporated into the "documentation" of the system, but some may not, or are extensively reduced in size via summarization in the process..

Comment: While I partially agree with this, I was suggesting documentation in the context of a project's documentation process, where in my organization includes any and all logs resulting from the testing of a new system and feature. This does not necessarily include what I would normally think of as documentation either, but I think it fits the bill quite nicely.

Comment: Curated portions of test logs might fit in permanent usage-guiding documentation if they contain information relevant to a given portion of the document, but it seems like the asker is referring to logging in production and a system for merging logs from different sources into some other kind of log. Sure, parts of the final merged log might be used *in* documentation, but the log itself would not be considered IT documentation.

Comment: @jaichele In that case, the *process* is described as "documentation", but not the logs themselves.

Answer (score 3):

While I think "history" and "journal" are both close to what I want, the suggestion of "history" brought to mind *[activity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/activity)*:

> Use (of internet, playstation, bank account etc.).

Of course, the problem of what to call the individual pieces of data remains: *activity items*? *activity records*?

Comment: We built a similar system and I would also go with activity. I would call those individual entities *activity records*. If not, history is the next most appropriate suggestion IMO.

Comment: "activity log" maybe?

Answer (score 2):

How about "events?"  You could then classify them as "software-created events" and "user-created events."

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
A suggestion is not an answer.
A good answer is comprehensive and contains evidence showing why it is correct.
Links to external resources are encouraged.
Answers which consist of virtually nothing but an unsupported statement or a citation are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Comment: I disagree.  A suggestion is an answer when the original poster is asking for one.  The original poster said, "I'm hoping to find a word or short phrase which..."  "Hoping to find A word", not "hoping to find THE word."

Answer (score 2):

*annotated log*

"This is the *annotated* component. It combines the data in the notes and log components."

---

**annotate** an·no·tate /ˈanəˌtāt/ verb

> add notes to (a text or diagram) giving explanation or comment. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=annotated&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=annotated%20definition)

Comment: I didn't see the other answer (*annotation*) before I suggested *annotated*. But I will leave mine because the verb form is a lot less clumsy for this instance. I.e., "a log *with* annotations" vs. "annotated log"

Answer (score 2):

You are already using two words, *notes* and *log,*
according to definitions that are highly specialized to your
particular context.
You expect users of your system to read the documentation that uses these
words and not be confused or misled by other closely-related
(but different) meanings of those words.

That's reasonable; people do this sort of thing all the time when
describing software systems.

Now you want a word that means "notes or log entries" in this specialized
sense, without other possible meanings that might cause confusion
or misunderstanding.

But why must it be one word? We often use multiple-word phrases to
describe things when one word is not specific enough.

Since you are describing something that combines the *notes* component
with the *log* component, why not use the words *notes* and *log*
combined in a phrase? For example,

> This is the **notes and log** component. It combines the data in the notes component and the data in the log component.

This has the advantage that you have already trained users to use your specialized definitions of the words *notes* and *log* when reading your
documentation, so they will naturally apply those same restricted senses
of those words in order to understand what is in this new component.

There are other ways you can combine the words *notes* and *log,*
such as **notes-log,**
in case you wish to avoid the word *and.*